# MQL4 - ArrayCopy - Copy a One-dimension Array to a Multidimensional Array Element

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mt4

I want to copy an array `"a"`, which is an array of doubles, into `"as"`, which is an array of arrays of doubles. Don't know why, but I cant, Either I get compile-time errors or execute-time errors.

The code I have is:

```
double a [10];
double as [][10];
```

... I populate `"a"` and `"as"` with elements...

And now I want to copy `"a"` into `"as"`, in the position #2.

I've tried several possible ways, like:

```
ArrayCopy(a[2],a);
```

But still I can't get it. Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I've not found any other solution for this issue, I've finally coded my own function, using a nested FOR, so I insert the values of a 1-dimension array into the appropriate positions of the 2-dimension array.

That one has been the best solution for me.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing. Do you know by chance if it's possible to copy a multi-dimensional array to another (or the same) multi-dimensional array by ArrayCopy()?

Comment: Documentation says it doesn't copy complex structures or classes (complex = they require initialization, for example), so I'm not sure. I would say it doesn't, but I would try. Have you tried with a simple 2-dim arrays?